# Apple Health: collecting and combining step data from multiple devices with different Apple IDs

Tags: iphone, apple-id, health.app

I have 2 iPhones: work and personal. For IT dept. reasons, I have to use a different Apple ID on each device: a work Apple ID and a personal Apple ID.

I track my steps in Apple Health on my personal iPhone, under my personal Apple ID.

Sometimes I carry both devices, sometimes I carry only one. Is there a way to set it up so that whichever device I'm carrying (work, personal or both) all my steps will be collected (and de-duplicated) under my personal Apple ID? (So I miss tracking as few as possible.)

I suspect there might be a way to do this by collecting data to a third party app that I have on both devices, but which only writes to Apple Health on the personal device.

Comment: Related question: "What stops step data from the accelerometers on the phone and watch from doubling up?" http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245210/what-stops-step-data-from-the-accelerometers-on-the-phone-and-watch-from-doublin

Comment: Do you not want to manually add the health data from one device to the other?  I think that's the only way you can do it while keeping the data on your personal Apple ID.

Comment: @fbara - Don't want to do that as it'd involve manually de-duplicating data (plus effort!).